# Update counterCache field, but don't update 'modified' field in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a content model and a comment model. On insertion of comment I am updating the comment_count in content table using counterCache feature of cakephp(belongsTo relation), but that time it is also updating the modified date in content table which I don't want. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom method for that counting and updating and call it in afterSave() of your comments model and when you save the new count to the associated table make sure

```
$data['Item']['modified'] = false;
```

modified is set to false.

Comment: I don't feel like this is an adequate solution. The built-in functionality that CakePHP provides for counterCache is extremely valuable, and for that matter, free.

I agree that this is definitely *a* way to do this, but that is a lot of work, especially if you are running multiple counters, as I am in my application.

Comment: Err... it already supports multiple counters, finders and callbacks. Have you read the docs? http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html If you know a way that requires *less* work *and* integrates with what is already there let us know.